# Create multiple pivot tables on one sheet next to each other

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Thanks in advance for any help with this. I have a VBA code that loops through all the excel sheets in active workbook (with the exception of three specifically excluded in the code). The heading starts in cell A7 and the data struture is dynamic in terms of columns and rows. The VBA should create the pivot table for each worksheet on a newly added sheet (in this code called "ExAnte") right next to each other. BUT, the `Set PvtTab` line, below, does not work and I keep receiving the error msg "Invalid procedure call or argument". Does anyone know what might be the issue here? I simply cannot see it...

```
Sub ExAnteSelection()
    
    Dim startCell As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim pvtCache As pivotCache
    Dim PvtTab As pivotTable
    Dim pivotRange As Range
    Dim nextColumn As Long
  
    ' Add a new worksheet for the pivot table
    Set ws2 = Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet)
    ws2.Name = "ExAnte"
    ws2.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' Color code RGB 0/0/225
    
    nextColumn = 1 ' Initialize the column index for placing pivots

    ' Loop through all worksheets except the specified ones
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Personnel_EMPLOYEES" And ws.Name <> "Personnel_NON_EMPLOYEES" And ws.Name <> "Travel" Then
            ' Find last row and column on the current sheet
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = ws.Cells(7, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            ' Define the range to use for the pivot table
            ws.Range("A7", ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Name = "DynamicRange"

            ' Create Pivot Table
            Set pvtCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ws.Range("DynamicRange"))
            Set PvtTab = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws2.Cells(3, nextColumn), TableName:="PivotTable_" & ws.Name)
            
            ' Increment the column index for placing pivots
            nextColumn = nextColumn + PvtTab.TableRange1.Columns.Count + 1
        End If
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

I tried all, searching the forum here, ChatGPT - even that guy cannot see the issue in the code :-)

Again, thank you!

Comment: For which worksheet does the error occur? I suppose, you have to exclude "ExAnte" from your worksheet-loop as well!

Answer (score 0):

Sheet `ExAnte` should be in exception list.

```
        If ws.Name <> "Personnel_EMPLOYEES" And ws.Name <> "Personnel_NON_EMPLOYEES" _
            And ws.Name <> "Travel" And ws.Name <> "ExAnte" Then
```

A tidy approach to get the same result.

```
If InStr("Personnel_EMPLOYEES|Personnel_NON_EMPLOYEES|Travel", ws.Name) = 0 Then
```